# Iterating over dictionary items(), values(), keys() in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

If I understand correctly, in Python 2, `iter(d.keys())` was the same as `d.iterkeys()`. But now, `d.keys()` is a view, which is in between the list and the iterator. What's the difference between a view and an iterator?

In other words, in Python 3, what's the difference between

```
for k in d.keys()
    f(k)
```

and

```
for k in iter(d.keys())
    f(k)
```

Also, how do these differences show up in a simple `for` loop (if at all)?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

*I'm not sure if this is quite an answer to your questions but hopefully it explains a bit about the difference between Python 2 and 3 in this regard.*

In Python 2, `iter(d.keys())` and `d.iterkeys()` are not quite equivalent, although they will behave the same. In the first, `keys()` will return a copy of the dictionary's list of keys and `iter` will then return an iterator object over this list, with the second a copy of the full list of keys is never built.

The view objects returned by `d.keys()` in Python 3 are *iterable* (i.e. an iterator can be made from them) so when you say `for k in d.keys()` Python will create the iterator for you. Therefore your two examples will behave the same.

The significance in the change of the return type for `keys()` is that the Python 3 view object is dynamic. i.e. if we say `ks = d.keys()` and later add to `d` then `ks` will reflect this. In Python 2, `keys()` returns a list of all the keys currently in the dict. Compare:

**Python 3**

```
>>> d = { "first" : 1, "second" : 2 }
>>> ks = d.keys()
>>> ks
dict_keys(['second', 'first'])
>>> d["third"] = 3
>>> ks
dict_keys(['second', 'third', 'first'])
```

**Python 2.x**

```
>>> d = { "first" : 1, "second" : 2 }
>>> ks = d.keys()
>>> ks
['second', 'first']
>>> d["third"] = 3
>>> ks
['second', 'first']
```

As Python 3's `keys()` returns the dynamic object Python 3 doesn't have (and has no need for) a separate `iterkeys` method.

**Further clarification**

In Python 3, `keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object but if we use it in a `for` loop context `for k in d.keys()` then an iterator is implicitly created. So the difference between `for k in d.keys()` and `for k in iter(d.keys())` is one of implicit vs. explicit creation of the iterator.

In terms of another difference, whilst they are both dynamic, remember if we create an explicit iterator then it can only be used once whereas the view can be reused as required. e.g.

```
>>> ks = d.keys()
>>> 'first' in ks
True
>>> 'second' in ks
True
>>> i = iter(d.keys())
>>> 'first' in i
True
>>> 'second' in i
False             # because we've already reached the end of the iterator
```

Also, notice that if we create an explicit iterator and then modify the dict then the iterator is invalidated:

```
>>> i2 = iter(d.keys())
>>> d['fourth'] = 4
>>> for k in i2: print(k)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

In Python 2, given the existing behaviour of `keys` a separate method was needed to provide a way to iterate without copying the list of keys whilst still maintaining backwards compatibility. Hence `iterkeys()`

Comment: there is `.viewkeys()` in 2.7. which returns view. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys

Comment: Thank you. I understand how Python 2's `d.keys()` is different. But I'm still confused as to the difference between `d.iterkeys()` from Python 2, `d.keys()` from Python 3, and `iter(d.keys())` from Python 3. As far as I understand, they are all dynamic, and none of them builds the list upfront?

Comment: In the `for` loop there is no difference between `iter(d.keys())` and `d.keys()`, as python internally calls `iter` itself. Also there is no difference between python 2.x `d.iterkeys()` and py3k `iter(d.keys())` : both return dictionary-key-iterator. So all three are virtually the same.