# Python: Outputting the correct value from a list()

Tags: python

I have a csv file that I've turned into a `list()` so that I can iterate over it to do some simple transformations with the data, however when I try to get the output I only get the key for each of the items (when what I need are the values).

The code I'm using right now is as follows (slightly truncated for clarity):

```
lines = list(csvdataFishes)
while (startTime + 30) > timeToEpoch(currLine['timestamp']) >= startTime:
    cx = someFunction1()
    uf = someFunction2()
    rf = someFunction3()
    pc = someFunction4()
    outline = [k for k in lines[i] if k is not ''] + [cx,uf,rf,pc]
    print ','.join(outline)
    i += 1
    currLine = lines[i]
startTime = startTime + 30
```

If I do a simple print `lines[i]` I get something like:

```
{
'adjusted timestamp': '2014-08-23 17:20:05.43000', 
'fishType': 'small green fish', 
'playerID': '3', 
'timestamp': '2014-08-23 16:21:05.430000-05:00', 
'targetID': '34', 
'lights': '1', 
'event': 'MakeSpawnFish'
}
```

but the output of print `','.join(outline)` just gives me the keys for the `[k for k in lines[i] if k is not '']` and the correct output for `[cx,uf,rf,pc]` (like so):

`adjusted timestamp,fishType,playerID,timestamp,targetID,lights,event,1,1,2,1`

What I'm wondering is how I get it to give the values (and not the key) for the `[k for k in lines[i] if k is not '']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines is a list of dicts.  If you iterate over a dict, you get its keys.  To get the values instead, use `dict.values()`.  So you need to change this line:

```
outline = [k for k in lines[i] if k is not ''] + [cx,uf,rf,pc]
```

to

```
outline = [k for k in lines[i].values() if k is not ''] + [cx,uf,rf,pc]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `keys` and `values` builtins:

```
>>> [k for k in lines[i].keys() if k is not '']
['fishType', 'timestamp', 'event', 'targetID', 'playerID', 'lights', 'adjusted timestamp']
```

and

```
>>> [k for k in lines[i].values() if k is not '']
['small green fish', '2014-08-23 16:21:05.430000-05:00', 'MakeSpawnFish', '34', '3', '1', '2014-08-23 17:20:05.43000']
```

These will iterate over the dictionary's keys and values. Check out the [dictionary documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: using lines[i].iterkeys() and lines[i].itervalues() might be better?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616721/iterating-over-dictionary-items-values-keys-in-python-3). @XiaotianPei I used `keys` and `values` because they are Python 2 and Python 3 compatible.

Comment: This is great - similar to 1.618's answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
[ lines[k] for k in lines if k is not '']
```

**Test**

```
>>> lines = {
... 'adjusted timestamp': '2014-08-23 17:20:05.43000', 
... 'fishType': 'small green fish', 
... 'playerID': '3', 
... 'timestamp': '2014-08-23 16:21:05.430000-05:00', 
... 'targetID': '34', 
... 'lights': '1', 
... 'event': 'MakeSpawnFish'
... }

>>> ",".join( [ lines[k] for k in lines if k is not ''] + ["1", "1", "2", "1"])
'2014-08-23 17:20:05.43000,small green fish,3,2014-08-23 16:21:05.430000-05:00,34,1,MakeSpawnFish,1,1,2,1'
```

Comment: But lines is not a dict, it's a list of dicts.

Comment: @1.618 Yeah I noticed that. The answer shows how to retrieve keys as op has written *how I get it to give the values (and not the key) for the*